# Google Apps Script Check for Duplicate Calendar event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I was able to successfully create a calendar event using the code below but unable to figure out why it creates another calendar event when it already exists. I have reviewed the various posts and can't seem to make the code to not create another calendar event.
I have a feeling it is something simple but I spent hours reviewing various posts and videos and can't get it to work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciate to delete a duplicate calendar entry. Below is an example of the data used to create the calendar event. [image]

```
 function CreateCalendarEvent() {
  const ID = '1MkimspZROYFPFApQECWHETIwMkWfQ5aizj0Da17cVhs';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName('Database');
  var index = 2; // This indicates start looking at row 2
  var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  for (;index<=LastRow; index++){
  var taskTitle = sheet.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
  var taskDesc = "Check On Me"//sheet.getRange(index,3,1,1).getValue();
  var startDate = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
  var checkOnMe = sheet.getRange(index,7,1,1).getValue();     
        
  if (checkOnMe == "Yes" && taskTitle && startDate && endDate)
  {
   var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("User_Form")[0].getEvents(startDate, 
   endDate);
   delete_events(events);
   var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("User_Form") 
 [0].createEvent(taskTitle,startDate,endDate,{description: taskDesc});

  }

 }// End of Loop

 }// End of Create Calendar

function delete_events(events){
 for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
      ev.deleteEvent();
 
 }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample sheet with dummy data for replication?

Comment: If you have the event id's in the spreadsheet then you can always look for them in the calendar before creating duplicates.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 - I added a screen shot shows an example of the data the I am using to create the calendar event. I am using a google form and is saved onto the sheet and the app script to runs after the user hits submit.

Comment: @Cooper - Sorry, I am sure how to get the event id's. I have been researching how to automatically update the google sheet after the event is created with "Yes" in a new column. I was thinking this may be an option to create a new event or not.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 - I added a screen shot shows an example of the data the I am using to create the calendar event. The data source is from a google form and the app script to runs after the user hits submit and populates the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Google Form that accepts event data. The form is linked to a spreadsheet that contains a script which updates Google Calendar with new event data. The script is triggered by an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger. But the script is always creating duplicate events.

**Cause**

`for (;index<=LastRow; index++){`

**Every** time the script runs, it processes **every** item in the spreadsheet. Hence the duplicate events.

**Solution**

- use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to process ONLY the latest submission.

**Changes**

- change the name of the script to `CreateCalendarEvent(e)` - this will ensure that Event Objects are available to the script.
- refer the script below

  - `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` - for debugging only; this will show the value of EVERY Event Object every time the script is run
  - no loop
  - `index` = the row of the latest submission
  - `taskTitle`, `taskDesc`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `checkOnMe` : values reference the row number indicated by `index`. An alternative would be to use `sheet.getDataRange().getValues` and then reference the variables (using `index`) by array values.

---

```
function CreateCalendarEvent(e) {
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Database')
 
  // get Event Objects
  var index = e.range.rowStart
  var taskTitle = sheet.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
  var taskDesc = "Check On Me"//sheet.getRange(index,3,1,1).getValue();
  var startDate = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
  var checkOnMe = sheet.getRange(index,7,1,1).getValue();    
          
  if (checkOnMe == "Yes" && taskTitle && startDate && endDate)
  {
   var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("User_Form")[0].getEvents(startDate, endDate);
   delete_events(events);
   var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("User_Form")[0].createEvent(taskTitle,startDate,endDate,{description: taskDesc});
  }
 }// End of Create Calendar
```

---